# Is there a Pydantic convention for a Model attribute that will default to a function of another attribute?

Tags: python, python-typing, pydantic

I want to define a Pydantic `BaseModel` with the following properties:

- Two `int` attributes `a` and `b`.
- `a` is a required attribute
- `b` is optional, and will default to `a+1` if not set.

Is there a way to achieve this? This is what I've tried.

```py
from typing import Optional

from pydantic import BaseModel, validator


class A(BaseModel):
    a: int
    b: Optional[int] = None  # want to default to a+1 if not set
    
    @validator('b', always=True)
    def default_b_value(cls, b, values):
        if b is None and 'a' in values:
            return values['a']+1
        return b
```

My problem with this is it doesn't match the guarantees of `A`. For any `A` that's actually constructed, `b` will never be `None` so its type should be `int`, not `Optional[int]`.

Answer (score 3):

I would not presume to know about *conventions* for this, but to achieve the behavior you want, you have a few options.

One way is to define `b` as being of the type `int` and setting a [`default_factory`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/models/#field-with-dynamic-default-value) to return a sentinel value, then identity-check for that value in the validator, similar to what you did with `None`. I suppose the cleanest way (in the type safety sense) would be to subclass `int` just for that purpose to have an object that is actually *distinct* while still being of the correct *type*.

```py
from typing import Any, cast

from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, validator


class _SentinelInt(int):
    pass


_sentinel_int = _SentinelInt()


class Foo(BaseModel):
    a: int
    b: int = Field(default_factory=lambda: _sentinel_int)

    @validator("b", always=True)
    def default_b_value(cls, v: int, values: dict[str, Any]) -> int:
        if v is _sentinel_int:
            return cast(int, values["a"] + 1)
        return v
```

Side note: You can be sure that the `a` value is present in the `values` dictionary because validation occurs in the order that fields are defined.

Demo:

```py
foo1 = Foo(a=42)
foo2 = Foo(a=-1, b=69)
print(foo1.json(indent=4))
print(foo2.json(indent=4))
```

Output:

```json
{
    "a": 42,
    "b": 43
}
```

```json
{
    "a": -1,
    "b": 69
}
```

---

An arguably *less* clean way would be to simply stick with `None` as the default but still type `b` as `int` and simply set a specific `type: ignore` directive for the default assignment:

```py
from typing import Any, cast

from pydantic import BaseModel, validator


class Foo(BaseModel):
    a: int
    b: int = None  # type: ignore[assignment]

    @validator("b", always=True)
    def default_b_value(cls, v: int, values: dict[str, Any]) -> int:
        if v is None:
            return cast(int, values["a"] + 1)
        return v
```

From the perspective of the type checker and for all intents and purposes at runtime the value of the `b` field of any instance will **always** be an `int`, so I would say this approach is well justified. Even though it may not be *strictly* type safe, the intent is still crystal clear.